# Like Action with Open Graph

Tags: api, facebook-like, action, facebook-opengraph

In the past creating likes was not allowed with the Facebook API.

Now that open graph has sort of make actions, objects generic. Can like be used with the open graph API; to like an object within my application.

If not, can I create my own "Like" action to be used within my application?

Comment: I am not sure if you are talking about liking a page and stuff like that within application but you can post "Read", "Cook" etc feed on user's timeline. Checkout this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Comment: I understand all that. I am trying to figure out if the like action is considered to be just another open graph action or if I need to create my own version of the like action to use it in opengraph.

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: @datasage did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is rather redundant now. Like is now a built in open graph action that you can add to your application.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, you cannot use the Open Graph API to *like* an object, because you can only *like* an object instance, not an object itself.

That said, I found how to *like* an object instance with a simple request (you just need to know the object instance id) :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[object_id]/likes
```